# Compile libstdc++ with hash style SYSV

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, sysv

Is there any way to compile GCC's libstdc++ with hash style SYSV instead of GNU/Linux? I have a toolchain (via crosstool-ng) that I use to compile our company library to work with a very wide range of Linux systems.

One of these system is a very old RedHat that have only SYSV hash style, when I compile a C only library/program with the toolchain, it works great since the generated binary uses SYSV.

But, when I link with libstdc++, the binary automatically changes to GNU/Linux style, the reason is because libstdc++ was built as GNU/Linux, hence the question.

Running the binary in this system gives me the error

```
ELF file OS ABI invalid
```

Just for completeness, I have already tried -Wl,--hash-style=sysv, without success.

Also, I have another toolchain for ARM system which have the same version of GCC, GLIBC, etc, but in this toolchain libstdc++ uses SYSV, dunno why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to rebuild your GCC with *[--disable-gnu-unique-object](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)* configure option. According to documentation on GCC configure options:

> --enable-gnu-unique-object
>
> --disable-gnu-unique-object
>
> Tells GCC to use the gnu_unique_object relocation for C++ template static data members and inline function local statics. Enabled by default for a toolchain with an assembler that accepts it and GLIBC 2.11 or above, otherwise disabled.

Using gnu_unique_object may lead to GNU ABI in your final executable, which is not supported in old Red Hat.