# Trouble understanding gcc linker options

Tags: gcc, linker

I have recently been reading up on linkers and I'm having trouble understanding this compilation code. If I were to run `gcc -Wl,--hash-style=both example.c`, what difference will it make as opposed to me simply running `gcc example.c`. And also, what does `--hash-style` means

Answer (score 5):

> what does `--hash-style` means

`--hash-style` allows you to change the format of hashtable which is used for runtime symbol resolution (see [Drepper's article](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), section "The GNU-style Hash Table" for details). The GNU hashtable format is said to be slightly faster.

> If I were to run `gcc -Wl,--hash-style=both example.c`,
>   what difference will it make as opposed to me simply running `gcc example.c`

It depends on how your distro's GCC was configured. AFAIK most use either `both`  or `gnu` styles by default. `Both` simply means that linked files will include, um, both `gnu` and `sysv` hashtables. This shouldn't matter unless you try to run your program on a system with dynamic linker which does not understand GNU hashtables. In that case, if program was built with `-Wl,--hash-style=gnu`, you'll get an error at startup about unsupported hashtable format.

Comment: Can you give an example for "system with dynamic linker which does not understand GNU hashtables"?

Comment: @KirilKirov I can't point to concrete distro/revision but people [do report about such systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132507/compile-libstdc-with-hash-style-sysv).